# Remove the day name

Tags: php

I have the following dates. How can I remove the day name?

```
giovedì 12 settembre 2012 => 12 settembre 2012
lunedì 1 gennaio 2011 => 1 gennaio 2011
mercoledì 14 luglio 2013 => 14 luglio 2013
```

Thank you

Comment: remove the day name from where? Is the above PHP var dump? or HTML? How is it generated? What does you code look like?

Comment: Your post shows no effort in researching the solution and also your question is not properly asked.

Comment: I have this string: "giovedì 12 settembre 2012"
I want this string: "12 settembre 2012"
Sorry if I don't made myself clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the first word and the following space in your `$string`, where `$string` contains the date you want to edit, you can do:

```
$string = 'giovedì 12 settembre 2012';
$string = preg_replace('/^\w+\ /u', '', $string);
```

But if you obtain the date using the `date()` function, you can format passing arguments, just read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). For example

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT'); // set locale to Italian
$string = date("d F Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 12, 2012));
```

should give you `12 settembre 2012`.

Comment: $string = preg_replace('/^\w+\ /', '', $string) doesn't work.

Comment: try adding `u` this way: '/^\w+\ /u'. Probably the problem is `ì`. I'm editing the answer

Answer (score 1):

If the date is always a string containing 4 'parts' (dayname, daynumber, monthname and year), seperated by a space you can do:

```
$str = "giovedì 12 settembre 2012";
$vals = explode(" ", $str);
$newStr = implode(" ", array_slice($vals, 1, 3));
```